# InfoPath form editable to some people and read only to others?

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer, infopath, forms-services

Is it possible to have some controls in an InfoPath form editable to only a certain group of people and read only to everyone else?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'd want to create views and use rules to display the views based on the logged in user I believe is the protocol.

Comment: Yup, and here is a detailed how-to http://claytoncobb.wordpress.com/2009/07/19/infopath-user-roles-in-browser-enabled-forms-using-groups/

Comment: Should really be an answer Jesus so you get credit for it.

Comment: this lets me access groups on my main SharePoint server, but how do I access groups that are created on a sub-site?